# How to modify a text within string using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to change a file containing strings like:

```
Record 1 : 
{ "K1":"value1" , 
  "K2":"value2" 
}

Record 2 :
{ "K1":"value3" , 
  "K2":"value4" 
}
```

to

```
{
    "Record_1" : 
        { "K1": "value1", 
          "K2": "value2" 
    }, 

    "Record_2" :
        { "K1": "value3", 
          "K2": "value4" 
        }
}
```

(to make it into a correct JSON format).
 
The part of code that I'm having problems with is:

```
pattern = r"(\s*)Record (\d+):"
all_records_json = re.sub(middle_pattern, "\"Record_"+ ??? + "\" : ",all_records)
```

And I don't know what to put instead of ??? so that it reads the (\d+) part that matched the pattern.

Comment: The result still isn't anything close to valid JSON. You can't have a `key: value` outside of an object, you can't have consecutive anythings without commas between them, etc.

Comment: abarnert is right, take a look at http://www.json.org/

Comment: That's true. Sorry I didn't put the whole thing. Those formatting parts I have taken care of. The record ids is the part that's causing problems now.

Comment: Also, your pattern doesn't match anything in your input data. `re.findall(pattern, all_records)` will return `[]`. So, the question of what to substitute in the pattern doesn't even come into it.

Comment: Also, using backslashes unnecessarily makes your code really hard to read. To put `"` characters into a string, use single instead of double quotes. And you probably want to use a raw string for the substitution as well as the pattern.

Comment: If you fix all these problems, the python object you want to look at is [`re.MatchObject.group()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject). Also see the docs for [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your pattern doesn't actually match your data in the first place:

```
>>> all_records = '''Record 2 :
... { "K1":"value3" , 
...   "K2":"value4" 
... }'''
>>> pattern = r"(\s*)Record (\d+):"
>>> re.findall(pattern, all_records)
[]
```

That's because your data has a space between the digits and the colon. You need to fix that. While we're at it, I have no idea why you're putting a group around the preceding whitespace, so let's not do that. So we get:

```
>>> pattern = r"\s*Record (\d+)\s*:"
>>> re.findall(pattern, all_records)
[2]
```

Now, your only capturing group is the `\d+`. So that will be group 1. Which you can include in the substitution as `\1`. So:

```
>>> print(re.sub(pattern, r'"Record_\1": ', all_records))
"Record_2":
{ "K1":"value3" ,
  "K2":"value4"
}
```

That still isn't valid JSON, but it's what you wanted, right?

If you read the docs, [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) explains that "Backreferences, such as `\6`, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern." For full details on back references for both `(…)` groups and `(?P<name>…)` groups, look them up in the [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). You should also read the [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), which explains all of this in a more novice-friendly way.

Notice that I made the substitution a raw string just like the pattern, so I didn't have to escape the `\1`, and I also used single instead of double quotes, so I didn't have to escape the `"` characters.

Comment: Ah. thanks. The "\1" was what I was looking for and didn't know how to search for it. Thanks.